# Using form to set a variable id for getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, getelementbyid

i wanted to put a variable from a form as Id for document.getElementById.
Here's what I've tried to do, but I can't get it to work.

```
<input type="text" id="data">
<input type="button" value="don" onclick="func(x)">

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("data")
function func(x){
document.getElementById(x).write(x + " *")
}
</script>
```

Comment: You got the element in "x" then why are you again going for `document.getElementById(x).write(x + " *")` ?

Comment: Where do you want to write the value. I mean in which tag?

Comment: In a simple HTML <p> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set text to p tag, use like

```
<input type="text" id="data">
<p id="pdata"></p>
<input type="button" value="don" onclick="func()">

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("data");

function func(){
document.getElementById("pdata").innerHTML = x + " *";
}
</script>
```

if you want to send id of control as parameter

```
<input type="text" id="data">
<input type="button" value="don" onclick="func('data')">

<script>
function func(x){
var x = document.getElementById("data").value;
document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = x + " *";
}
</script>
```